# return to home page

Tags: android

In my app there is a seeings page and a Home page,In the settings page i want to enter a password and will be read it in a file after pressing the ok button i want return to home page

The code i tried is.....

```
    public class SetteingsPage extends Activity 
      {
Button okBtn,resetBtn,cancelBtn;
TextView passwordTxt,passwordTxt2;
String passwordTxtValue,passwordTxtValue2;
String value;
String localDataPassword;
int id=1;
OpenHelper db_obj;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PASSWORD_DATA = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String FILENAME1 = "password.txt";

 @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.settingspage);
      db_obj = new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());

      okBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1s);

      passwordTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1s);
      passwordTxt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2s);

      resetBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreset);
      cancelBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancels);

        passwordTxt.setHint("Enter Password");
        passwordTxt2.setHint("Confirm Password");



      try {
          System.out.println("Enter try block!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME1);
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            localDataPassword = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("localDataPassword"+localDataPassword);
            System.out.println("dasretetile"+localDataPassword);

        } catch (Exception e) { 

        }


       if(localDataPassword == null || localDataPassword.equals("") || localDataPassword.equals("null"))
       {
           resetBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String id1 = Integer.toString(id);
                      passwordTxtValue = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
                      passwordTxtValue2 = passwordTxt2.getText().toString();

                      if(passwordTxt.getText().length()>=5)
                      {
                      if(passwordTxtValue.equals(passwordTxtValue2))
                      {

                            try 
                            {
                                db_obj.password_varification(id1, passwordTxtValue);
                                Log.e("Insert Values"," " );

                            } 
                            catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                            }



                             FileOutputStream fos;
                                try {
                                    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    fos.write(passwordTxtValue.getBytes());
                                    System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"
                                            + passwordTxtValue);
                                    fos.close();

                                   SetteingsPage.this.finish();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }




                      } 

                      else
                      {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter values correctly!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            passwordTxt.setText("");
                            passwordTxt2.setText("");
                      }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Should hhave min 5 characters!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            passwordTxt.setText("");
                            passwordTxt2.setText("");
                      }
                }
            });
       }
       else
       {
           okBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            passwordTxt.setHint("Old Password");
            passwordTxt2.setHint("New Password");
          resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String oldPassword  = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
                    String newPassword  = passwordTxt2.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("Old Password Value"+oldPassword);
                    System.out.println("From Reset Button"+localDataPassword);
                    System.out.println("New password"+newPassword);

                     if(passwordTxt.getText().length()>=5)
                     {
                    if(oldPassword.equals(localDataPassword))
                    {
                        FileOutputStream fos;
                            try {
                                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos.write(newPassword.getBytes());
                                System.out.println("-----stert----Data written to files is:"
                                        + newPassword);
                                fos.close();

                                Intent intent=new Intent(SetteingsPage.this,Home.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the old password correctly!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                    String dummy = Integer.toString(id);
                      db_obj.Deletrowpassword(dummy);


                }
                     else
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Should Have Minimum 5 Characters!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            passwordTxt.setText("");
                            passwordTxt2.setText("");
                     }
                }
            });
       }



   }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
             intent.putExtra("key", "common");
             startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
             finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
```

}

Both the code

```
       SetteingsPage.this.finish();
```

as well as

```
    Intent home  = new Intent();
     home.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
     startActivity(home);
```

tried but none of these are working...

The locat output is..

```
    01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.security/com.example.security.Home}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  01-11 12:39:44.218: E/AndroidRuntime(13506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` you are trying to access null value somewhere so make sure you are not doing this

Comment: @abcd You can try to debug you application from Eclipse and see at which line of execution `NullPointerException` is coming

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

Directly..after

TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.//);

... add this:
if (txt == null) { Log.w("", "TextView is null"); }
//

Comment: kindly add the logcat output here

Comment: update with complete code it will be easy to identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `finish` method for the current activity, if you already called `startActivityForResult` from within it.

Maybe this will help:

```
startActivity(intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
```

If it helps, give a thanks :)